# How do in-memory databases provide durability?

Tags: database, in-memory-database, durability

More specifically, are there any databases that don't require secondary storage (e.g. HDD) to provide durability?

Note:This is a [follow up of my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3336720/are-there-databases-that-bases-durability-on-redundancy-and-not-on-persistent-sto).

Comment: BTW Here is related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167063/adding-durability-to-in-memory-data-structures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want persistence of transations writing to persistent storage is only real option (you perhaps do not want to build many clusters with independent power supplies in independent data centers and still pray that they never fail simultaneously). On the other hand it depends on how valuable your data is. If it is dispensable then pure in-memory DB with sufficient replication may be appropriate. BTW even HDD may fail after you stored your data on it so here is no ideal solution. You may look at http://www.julianbrowne.com/article/viewer/brewers-cap-theorem to choose replication tradeoffs.

Prevayler http://prevayler.org/ is an example of in-memory system backed up with persistent storage (and the code is extremely simple BTW). Durability is provided via transaction logs that are persisted on appropriate device (e.g. HDD or SSD). Each transaction that modifies data is written into log and the log is used to restore DB state after power failure or database/system restart. Aside from Prevayler I have seen similar scheme used to persist message queues. 
This is indeed similar to how "classic" RDBMS works except that logs are only data written to underlying storage. The logs can be used for replication also so you may send one copy of log to a live replica other one to HDD. Various combinations are possible of course.

Answer (score 1):

All databases require non-volatile storage to ensure durability.  The memory image does not provide a durable storage medium.  Very shortly after you loose power your memory image becomes invalid.  Likewise, as soon as the database process terminates, the operating system will release the memory containing the in-memory image.  In either case, you loose your database contents.

Until any changes have been written to non-volatile memory, they are not truely durable.  This may consist of either writing all the data changes to disk, or writing a journal of the change being done.

In space or size critical instances non-volatile memory such as flash could be substituted for a HDD.  However, flash is reported to have issues with the number of write cycles that can be written.

Having reviewed your previous post, multi-server replication would work as long as you can keep that last server running.   As soon as it goes down, you loose your queue.  However, there are a number of alternatives to Oracle which could be considered.

PDAs often use battery backed up memory to store their databases.  These databases are non-durable once the battery runs down.  Backups are important.

Answer (score 1):

In-memory means all the data is stored in memory for it to be accessed. When data is read, it can either be read from the disk or from memory. In case of in-memory databases, it's always retrieved from memory. However, if the server is turned off suddenly, the data will be lost. Hence, in-memory databases are said to lack support for the durability part of ACID. However, many databases implement different techniques to achieve durability. This techniques are listed below.

- Snapshotting - Record the state of the database at a given moment in time. In case of Redis the data is persisted to the disk after every two seconds for durability.
- Transaction Logging - Changes to the database are recorded in a journal file, which facilitates automatic recovery.
- Use of NVRAM usually in the form of static RAM backed up by battery power. In this case data can be recovered after reboot from its last consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

classic in memory database can't provide classic durability, but depending on what your requirements are you can:

- use memcached (or similar) to storing in memory across enough nodes that it's unlikely that the data is lost
- store your oracle database on a SAN based filesystem, you can give it enough RAM (say 3GB) that the whole database is in RAM, and so disk seek access never stores your application down.  The SAN then takes care of delayed writeback of the cache contents to disk.  This is a very expensive option, but it is common in places where high performance and high availability are needed and they can afford it.
- if you can't afford a SAN, mount a ram disk and install your database on there, then use DB level replication (like logshipping) to provide failover.

Any reason why you don't want to use persistent storage?